# How does is.numeric work within a loop?

Tags: r, loops

I'm using `is.numeric` in a loop, and it doesn't seem to behave the way I would expect it to.

```
> for (d in strsplit("123","")){
>     print(as.numeric(d))
>     print(is.numeric(d))
>     }
```

returns...

```
[1] 1 2 3
[1] FALSE
```

I would expect it to evaluate "1", then "2", then "3" (the same way `as.numeric` evaluates each character) printing out a `FALSE` each time (since they're characters not numerics).

Why is this not the case?

Comment: `strsplit` returns a list of vectors, one for each value you pass in. Here you only passed in "123" so you get a list of length 1, you could have passed in multiple strings. It seems like you want `for (d in strsplit("123","")[[1]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here: a data type issue and a looping issue.

Like almost all functions in R, `strsplit` is vectorized, so its return value is suitable for cases in which its input is an "atomic" value (in R, a vector of length 1), or an actual vector: i.e. its value is a list, each element of which will contain the split corresponding to the value of the split string for each vector element:

```
str( strsplit( "123", "" ) )
List of 1
 $ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
```

Your loop is thus running each iteration on the elements of the list. In the case of your example, the input for `strsplit` is a vector of length 1, so its value is a list of length one, and the loop runs once, over a character vector of length 3 containing the empty-string split of the single element in the input vector.

`as.numeric` is a coercion function that will make its best attempt to turn its argument to a numeric vector, so *its value* will be numeric *even if its input is not*. `is.numeric` tests whether *its input* is numeric, and will have the value `FALSE` if it isn't. Compare:

```
for ( d in strsplit( "123","" ) ) {
    print( as.numeric( d ) )
    print( is.numeric( d ) ) 
    print( is.numeric( as.numeric( d ) ) )
}

for ( d in strsplit( "123", "" )[[1]] ) {
    print( as.numeric( d ) )
    print( is.numeric( d ) ) 
    print( is.numeric( as.numeric( d ) ) )
}
```